# cannot svn camera_info_manager package from source

Tags: ros, svn, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone can svn camera_info_manager package from source? I need electric version for Gumstix Overo. I tried this link https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/image_common/tags/image_common-1.6.1 , but it seems not exist.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54665/cannot-svn-camera_info_manager-package-from-source/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The entire [image_common](http://ros.org/wiki/image_common) stack has moved to github, including old release branches.

There are currently problems with the [wiki Releases page](http://ros.org/wiki/image_common/Releases), which make it hard to find the correct previous source versions.

Assuming that 1.6.1 is the release you want, you should be able to check out [this version](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/image_common-1.6).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-02-10**:
Thanks a lot !!!